# How to collect and send container logs from EKS using AWS OTEL collector?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, open-telemetry-collector, amazon-adot, aws-adot-collector

I am using aws ADOT collector for collecting and sending Xray traces and AMP metrics from my workload account where EKS cluster is running to central monitoring account.

As per the latest update of ADOT collector which now supports logging, I wanted to use move from fluent bit to ADOT collector and thus unify observability under single umbrella.

update: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/logs-support-aws-distro-opentelemetry/

AWS customer resource fir log collection as per latest docs : https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/adot-eks-add-on/config-container-logs

However ADTO collector awscloudwatchlog exporter is based Otel collector upstream there is no assume role arn option to allow service account to assume role in monitoring account and push log to cloudwatch.

Is there a way to collect and send log using AWS ADOT collector ( OTEL collector) cross account?